# iron-overlay-behavior styling not taking effect

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

According to [the docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-overlay-behavior?active=iron-overlay-backdrop), I can style my overlay with the attributes `--iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity` and `--iron-overlay-backdrop-background-color`.

This is what I am trying, but it is not having any effect on the underlying `iron-overlay-backdrop`:

```
<dom-module id="my-overlay">

    <style>
        :host {
            --iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity: 0.9;
            --iron-overlay-backdrop-background-color: #222;
        }
    </style>

    <template>
        <content></content>
    </template>

    <script>

        Polymer({
            is: 'my-overlay',

            behaviors: [
                Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior
            ],

            attached: function(){
                this.setAttribute('with-backdrop', '');
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

---

Inspecting in the broswer reveals that the `iron-overlay-backdrop` is retaining its default values for `opacity` and `background-color`:

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a bug, I have reported it here: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/issues/23

Answer (score 2):

iron-overlay-backdrop will be added to body, so you must apply these styles in your body like this:

```
<body>

  <style is="custom-style">
    iron-overlay-backdrop {
      --iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity: 0.9;
      --iron-overlay-backdrop-background-color: #222;
    }
  </style>

  <my-overlay></my-overlay>

</body>
```